# Java Help Recursion & Binary Trees

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I am somewhat new to Java, and very new to recursion and binary trees. I am building a program that takes text from a document and stores it in a binary tree. Then I need to take a string and find out how many times it appears in the text.

My problem(s) are either while I am adding the data and/or when I am searching the data for the string.

I have decided to store the string and the frequency in each node as it is built. So my add methods are as follows:

```
public void add(String newWord) {

    //Change the word case to make comparing easier
    newWord = newWord.toUpperCase();


    root = recursiveAdd(root, newWord);
}

/**
 * Takes the root and recurses until the root is null (base case)
 * Frequency is incremented if the data is being added, or if
 * it already exits. If the data is not present, the method recurses
 */
private Node recursiveAdd(Node subTree, String newWord) {

    //Base case: the root is null
    //Empty trees have a node created, set, and incr freq
    if (subTree == null) {  
        subTree = new Node();
        subTree.setStoredWord(newWord);
        subTree.incrFreqCount(); 
        return subTree;

    }


    int comparison = newWord.compareTo(subTree.getStoredWord());

    //For a word already in tree, increment the frequency
    if (comparison == 0) {

        if(newWord.equalsIgnoreCase("translyvania"))
        System.out.println("Entered same word incrementation");

        subTree.incrFreqCount();
        return subTree;

        //The root comes before the new word, then 
        //move on to the right child
    } else if(comparison < 0) {

        subTree.setLchild(recursiveAdd(subTree.getLchild(), newWord));

    } else { //if(comparison > 0) {

        subTree.setRchild(recursiveAdd(subTree.getRchild(), newWord));

    }
    return subTree;
}
```

I can't seem to tell where my problem is. For the word that I am searching, sometimes it says that it occurs 16 times(what I should get) and sometimes it says 1 time. It doesn't seem to be consistent at all and the value changes for seemingly no reason (though I know there must be one).

Once my tree is built, I then take the string that I am searching for, and pass it through these methods.

```
public void wordSearch(String lookForWord){

    lookForWord = lookForWord.toUpperCase();
    wordSearchRecur(root, lookForWord);

}



private boolean wordSearchRecur(Node subTree, String lookForWord){

    //Base case
    // The root is that same as the string
    if(subTree == null){
        System.out.println("The word \"" + lookForWord + "\" is not "
                + "found in the text");
        return false;
    }

    int comparison = lookForWord.compareTo(subTree.getStoredWord());

    if(comparison == 0){
        System.out.println("The word \"" + lookForWord + "\" is found " + 
                subTree.getFreqCount() + " times in the text");
        return true;


        //Alphabetically before, then move to left branch
    } else if (comparison < 0){

        System.out.println("move to left");
        return wordSearchRecur(subTree.getLchild(), lookForWord);

        //Alphabetically after, then move to right branch
    } else { // if(comparison > 0){
        System.out.println("move to right");
        return wordSearchRecur(subTree.getRchild(), lookForWord);
    }   

}
```

I also can't really understand why I am reaching the end of the wordSearchRecur() method. Shouldn't I be returning before it ever gets to that point? My output is showing that it reaches there several times.

I know I am missing huge parts of these concepts, but looking at all of the previous posts isn't helping. I must have spent 3 hours just on looking for an answer on Stack, not to mention all the other websites.

Please help!

EDIT: 
I edited the code to include what I have changed thanks to the help of @Joop Eggen I now have the frequency calculated correctly during the recursiveAdd(), but during the wordSearchRecur() the frequency does not seem to follow the node. Even when comparison == 0, the freqCount is still 1.

SOLVED: After the help of @Joop Eggen further problems were only a result of an oversight. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are reaching the end of the recursive method because you should return the results of the recursive calls. `return wordSearchRecur(root.getLchild(), lookForWord);` and `return wordSearchRecur(root.getRchild(), lookForWord);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will profit from first reducing the code to its simplest form.

```
public void add(String word) {

    //Change the word case to make comparing easier
    word = word.toUpperCase();

    root = recursiveAdd(root, word);
}

/**
 * Takes a sub-tree and recurses until the sub-tree is null (base case)
 * Frequency is incremented if the data is being added, or if
 * it already exists. If the data is not present, the method recurses
 */
private Node recursiveAdd(Node subtree, String word) {

    // Base case: the subtree is null
    if (subtree == null) {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.setStoredWord(word);
        node.incrFreqCount();
        return node;
    }

    int comparison = word.compareTo(subtree.getStoredWord());
    if (comparison == 0) {
        // For data already in tree, increment the frequency
        subtree.incrFreqCount();
    } else if (comparison  < 0) {
        subtree.setLchild(recursiveAdd(subtree.getLchild(), word);
    } else /*if (comparison > 0)*/ {
        subtree.setRchild(recursiveAdd(subtree.getRchild(), word);
    }
    return subtree;
}
```

As also searching:

```
public void wordSearch(String lookedForWord){   
    lookedForWord = lookedForWord.toUpperCase();
    wordSearchRecur(root, lookedForWord);
}

private boolean wordSearchRecur(Node subtree, String word){

    if (subtree == null) {
        System.out.println("The word \"" + word + "\" is not "
                + "found in the text");
        return false;
    }

    int comparison = word.compareTo(root.getStoredWord();
    if (comparison == 0){
        System.out.println("The word \"" + word + "\" is found " + 
                subtree.getFreqCount() + " times in the text");
        return true;
    } else if (comparison < 0) {
        return wordSearchRecur(subtree.getLchild(), word);
    } else /*if (comparison > 0)*/ {
        wordSearchRecur(subtree.getRchild(), word);
    }   
}
```

This helps keeping errors at bay, as there is less to check/go wrong.

As you did `toUpperCase` in both cases, and in the rewrite also the comparison is done the same (you had equals and turned around `compareTo` parameters, everything should work.

In fact the code shown looks quite alright. Make a recursive `dumpTree(Node subtree, String indentation)`. And check every step.

Possibly you edited the code here a bit, and originally some braces `{ }` were misplaced.

Comment: That makes it much much easier! It clears up a lot and I now have wordSearchRecur() coming up with the same freqCount that the recursiveAdd() is coming up with. However, from debugging I can see that during recursiveAdd() it is only entering the (comparison == 0) block 1 additional time. I am now getting a frequency of 2 and not 16.

Comment: Oops... I take that back. It's still at a frequency of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return in either of these cases:

```
//Alphabetically before, then move to left branch
if(lookForWord.compareTo(root.getStoredWord()) < 0){
    System.out.println("move to left");
    wordSearchRecur(root.getLchild(), lookForWord);

//Alphabetically after, then move to right branch
} else if(lookForWord.compareTo(root.getStoredWord()) > 0){
    System.out.println("move to right");
    wordSearchRecur(root.getRchild(), lookForWord);
}
```

You need to `return wordSearchRecur`, not just call it and throw away the result.

Comment: I posted the same as comment and not as an answer, since it doesn't explain why `For the word that I am searching, sometimes it says that it occurs 16 times(what I should get) and sometimes it says 1 time.`

Comment: Thanks for your help. That fixed the problem with hitting that last return. That part makes more sense. I'm still stuck on the other problem though.

Comment: @learned.beh Fixing the returns may have fixed it, but if you don't know what you change to make it break/work then I can't really help you. You need to identify something that works, something that doesn't, and then the difference between them.